# How can I query my table to group it by 2 fields in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck.

I'm trying to query one of my tables to obtain the maximum 'canister_change_date' with grouped pairs 'canister_type' and 'test_cell'.

I've put together a table with some dummy data (below) If you want the create table schema, let me know and I'll put it in the comments.
[image: 43]

The final result would either need to have the id's or the whole row with id.

expected result (below) would have id's - 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8

6 should be removed as matching pair (test_cell =4, canister_type=Carbon Monoxide) and 7 to be taken as it has the later 'canister_change_date' date.

The expect result would either need to have the id's or id's and rest of fields.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: show us your expected result in tabular form.

Comment: @Strawberry SQLfiddle is down at the moment.

Comment: Try https://dbfiddle.uk instead.

Comment: *SQLfiddle is down at the moment* https://dbfiddle.uk/ https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ...

Comment: Nowhere in that answer does it list sqlfiddle (or indeed any of the fiddle providers) as a *requirement*. Rather, they are a *nice to have*

Comment: *for each canister_type and for each test_cell.* What does it mean? maybe you mean - for each `(canister_type, test_cell)` pair?

Comment: @Akina yes, a unique pair between these components. For example if there were two rows with both same ```test_cell``` and ```canister_type``` it would select only the row with the latest date for ```canister_change_date```

Comment: If so use simple GROUP BY by this expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where test_cell = t.test_cell and canister_type = canister_type
    and canister_change_date > t.canister_change_date
)
```

or if your version of MySql is 8.0+ and supports window functions:

```
select t.* from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by test_cell, canister_type order by canister_change_date desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` on multiple columns just like that

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY column1, column2
```

If you want to find row with highest value of some column then you will need `HAVING` clause and `MAX()` aggregate function. You can combine them like this

```
SELECT max_column, column1, column2
GROUP BY column1, column2          
HAVING max_column = MAX(max_column)
```

This example assumes you want to find highest value of `max_column` for each unique pair of `column1` and `column2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kacper, unfortunately when I use this query the end result ID's do not match the ID's from the table. Any idea why?